# MatCheckbox - Angular Material - Unit tests - How to click to select/deselect all lines

Tags: angular, unit-testing, checkbox, angular-material, ngmodel

I use **MatCheckboxModule** from **Angular Material** in my Angular 5 application.

I have a table with multiple lines and a checkbox to select/deselect all lines from the table :

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectAll" (change)="toggleAll()">Toggle</mat-checkbox>
```

The component part is composed of a *selectAll* boolean property, a *selectedData* array property and a *toggleAll* function.
This function fills the *selectedData* array with all the lines if *selectAll* is true, otherwise, set the *selectedData* to empty.

Below, a component code extract:

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {

  booking: Booking;
  selectedData: Line[];
  private _selectAll: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this._selectAll = false;
    this.selectedData = [];
    this.getBooking();
  }

  get selectAll(): boolean {
    return this._selectAll;
  }

  set selectAll(newValue: boolean) {
    this._selectAll = newValue;
  }

  toggleAll() {
    for (const line of this.booking.lines) {
      this.selectAll ? this.selectedData.push(line) : this.selectedData = [];
    }
  }
}
```

This feature works. However, I don"t know how to test a click which will fill the selectedData array then will empty it. Indeed, in my following code, data are always push in my array because the *selectAll* property is not changed at the second click :

```
it(`should toggle all lines`, async(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    const checkbox = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.select-all-container mat-checkbox label');
    checkbox.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.selectedData.length).toEqual(component.booking.briefLines.length);
        checkbox.click();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.selectedData.length).toEqual(0);
        });
    });
}));
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think a fixture.detectChanges(); should update the selectAll property. Try this:

```
it(`should toggle all lines`, async(() => {
  component.ngOnInit();
  const checkbox = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.select-all-container mat-checkbox label');
  checkbox.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.selectedData.length).toEqual(component.booking.briefLines.length);
      checkbox.click();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          expect(component.selectedData.length).toEqual(0);
      });
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

At least in Angular version 8 (perhaps earlier) you need to target the internal hidden checkbox control:

```
const checkbox = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-checkbox-input');
checkbox.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Flow the doc of Angular test, import this firs in your test;

```
import { HarnessLoader } from '@angular/cdk/testing';
import { MatCheckboxHarness } from '@angular/material/checkbox/testing';
```

Crear a test component;

```
@Component({
  template: `<app-your-component
    [data]="inputData"
    (notifyTable)="handleNotifyTable($event)"
  ></app-your-component>`
})
class TestComponent {
  data = yourFixtureDataForTest();
  received = false;
  handleNotifyTable() {
    this.received = true;
  }
}
```

Declaration;

```
describe('YourMatCheckboxListComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;
```

Config before test;

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.directive(YourMatCheckboxListComponent)
    ).componentInstance;
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Test the selection and unselect checkbox;

```
 it('select one element and unselect', async () => {
    const checkbox = (await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatCheckboxHarness))[2];

    await checkbox.check();

    expect(component.selections.length).toEqual(1); // test list selection

    await checkbox.uncheck();

    expect(component.selections.length).toEqual(0); // after unselect
  });
```